# What is the Japanese word for "counter" and how do I ask questions with it?

Tags: grammar, counters

How do I ask questions like this? "What is the counter word for umbrellas?"

How do I give answers like this? "The counter word for umbrellas is 本."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Counter" "counter word" is [助数詞]{じょすうし}, but when you ask and respond to "What is the counter word for XX?" you'd usually say like...

> 「傘は何で数えますか？」
>   (*lit.* Do you count umbrellas with what?) 
>   --「（傘は）『本』で数えます。」
>
> 「傘はなんて/どうやって/どのように/どんなふうに/どういうふうに数えますか？」
>   (*lit.* How do you count umbrellas?)
>   --「（傘は）『一本、二本』と数えます。」
>
> 「傘の数え方は？」 (informal) 
>   (*lit.* The way of counting umbrellas is?) 
>   --「（傘の数え方は、）『一本、二本』です。」

(You *could* ask 傘の助数詞は何ですか？ *lit.* "What's the counter word of umbrellas?", but it's not very common to use the term 助数詞 in daily/normal conversation...)

Answer (score 3):

The term people would use in ordinary conversation is [単位]{たんい｝ (unit of measurement).

> 傘は何という単位で数えますか。

Comment: あ～確かに～ 「傘を数える(ときの)単位は？」とか言いますもんね。